# Non-linear shadow in HTML design

Tags: html, canvas, css

I'm trying to create a shadow that is wider in the top like in the picture below. It does not have to be very cross-browser, recent Firefox and WebKit based browser will do just fine. Does anyone have any good ideas on how to do this?

[image: shadow]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet tried this technique, but CSS3 includes the border-image property, as described [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/). Perhaps if you developed your own shadow, you might be able to set it as the border (or use a wrapper element with such a border).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try fiddling with `box-shadow` and the transform property’s [skew function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions). Maybe place a transparent div with `box-shadow` beneath the content element, e.g.:

```
#shadow{
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
       -moz-transform: skewY(-10deg);
         -o-transform: skewY(-10deg);
            transform: skewY(-10deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px;
       -moz-box-shadow: 4px;
         -o-box-shadow: 4px;
            box-shadow: 4px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just [wrote about something similar](http://nimbupani.com/drop-shadows-with-css3.html).

Answer (score -1):

photoshop or gimp, which u like

Comment: he's looking to do it in CSS and HTML5